# Cannot reference the non-static field

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Basically, I cannot run a thread when this procedure is non-static. If it comes static, I cannot access the GUI's form.

How do I run a thread on a non-static procedure?

```
Thread check = new Thread(refreshInfo);

    private void refreshInfo()
    {
        if (Program.loggedIn == true)
        {
            btnLogIn.Visible = false;
            btnRegister.Visible = false;

            lblLoggedIn.Text = "Logged in";

            btnUserSettings.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

**Error**

> Error 12  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'BLHClient.BLHClient.refreshInfo()'

Comment: You need to assign the `Thread` in your constructor.

Comment: Stupid mistake. I've fixed this before. Thanks Rob.

Comment: This code will crash. You can't modify a UI control from a background thread. Why use a raw thread anyway instead of using Tasks and `async/await`? You could perform whatever needed asynchronous processing and get back to the UI thread with a simple `await RunMyAsyncMethod();` call

Comment: How does await RunMyAsyncMethod work? Could you give me a tutorial post? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Use MVVM with binding and INotifyPropertyChanged - this will be cleaner and quicker to implement.

Comment: If you still wanted to do it this way, you could `Invoke(...)` a `MethodInvoker` in order to perform actions on the UI from that thread, although I don't think that's recommended.

Comment: None of these help in my circumstance and shouldn't be too complicated.